# How to force a new DHCP discover

Tags: macos, command-line, dhcp, osx-mavericks

I'm analysing my network traffic at home, and I want to force my Mac to completely renew its DHCP stuff. Renewing my DHCP lease only reveals two DHCP packets sent over my interface, but I want to see the whole process in [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark). Is there a command-line way to do this?

Comment: DHCP discovery can be accomplished with only 2 packets sent.  What makes you think there are more?

Comment: the _complete_ handshake should have more that 2 packets involved or? discover, offer, request, ack at least I think

Comment: Ah.  I misunderstood your use of "sent over my interface."  Your Mac sends the discover and request packets.  It receives the offer and ack packets.  Which two are you seeing?

Comment: Already solved. Now I can see all 4 packets in wireshark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to do it by toggling DHCP on/off with `sudo ipconfig set en0 none; sudo ipconfig set en0 dhcp`, or with doing something similar via the GUI.

Or try downing/upping the interface with `ifconfig en0 down; ifconfig en0 up`

I believe configd is the process where the DHCP client code lives. You could try sending a SIGHUP to configd with `sudo killall -HUP configd`, or just kill configd outright and let launchd auto-relaunch it: `sudo killall configd`. This suggestion is a bit extreme. Don't be surprised if you end up with networking in a weird state after this. If that happens, rebooting might be the easiest way to get it back in order.

Check out the man pages for `ipconfig`, `ifconfig` and `networksetup` for other ideas of how to perturb the interfaces from the command line.

Note: Check what the correct BSD unix-level interface identifier is for your interface, and replace `en0` in the examples above with the correct identifier for your situation.

Comment: thanks `sudo ipconfig set en0 none; sudo ipconfig set en0 dhcp`did the trick